# How can I improve this Makefile?

Tags: c++, makefile

I am working on creating a Makefile for my ProjectEuler solutions. I need to compile each solution into a separate binary for personal timing purposes. Is it possible to pass the name of the rule to the -o option to remove some repeated code?

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x
INC = -Iinclude/ -I../tools/

binaries=01sum35\
     02evenfibs\
     03largestprimefactor\
     04largestpallyproduct\
     05smallestmultiple\
     06sumsquaredifference\
     07tenthousandfirstprime\
     08largestproductinseries\
     09specialpythagtriplet

all: $(binaries)

01sum35: 
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 01sum35.cc $(INC) -o 01sum35  

02evenfibs:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 02evenfibs.cc $(INC) -o 02evenfibs

03largestprimefactor:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 03largestprimefactor.cc $(INC) -o 03largestprimefactor

04largestpallyproduct:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 04largestpallyproduct.cc ../tools/tools.cc $(INC) -o 04largestpallyproduct

05smallestmultiple:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 05smallestmultiple.cc $(INC) -o 05smallestmultiple

06sumsquaredifference:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 06sumsquaredifference.cc $(INC) -o 06sumsquaredifference

07tenthousandfirstprime:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 07tenthousandfirstprime.cc ../tools/tools.cc $(INC) -o 07tenthousandfirstprime

08largestproductinseries:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 08largestproductinseries.cc ../tools/tools.cc $(INC) -o 08largestproductinseries

09specialpythagtriplet:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) 09specialpythagtriplet.cc $(INC) -o 09specialpythagtriplet

clean:
    rm -f $(binaries)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes:

```
CXX       = g++
#
# Notice the +=.  Use CPPFLAGS rather than INC for pre-processor rules.
#
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude/ -I../tools/
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x

#
# Move the backslash
# This will stop it looking like a directory at first glance.
binaries=01sum35              \
     02evenfibs               \
     03largestprimefactor     \
     04largestpallyproduct    \
     05smallestmultiple       \
     06sumsquaredifference    \
     07tenthousandfirstprime  \
     08largestproductinseries \
     09specialpythagtriplet

all: $(binaries)

clean:
    rm -f $(binaries)

# Default rules and dependencies works for all the targets
# except the following which need one more file (dependency)

04largestpallyproduct:      04largestpallyproduct.cc    ../tools/tools.cc
07tenthousandfirstprime:    07tenthousandfirstprime.cc  ../tools/tools.cc
08largestproductinseries:   08largestproductinseries.cc ../tools/tools.cc
```

Answer (score 2):

A few extra things that add to the post from @LokiAstari
In the listing below:

1. Add some warnings, -Wall as a minimum
2. Use VPATH to find the source files for the tools
3. Mark targets that are not created as 'phony'.  This stops `make` from doing some searches and prevents the makefile failing if a file called `all` or `clean` ever exists.
4. Added some cleanup files
5. By making the binaries that depend on the tools depend on the `tools.o` object file not the source file, you avoid recompiling tools.cc for every binary.  Because we have a VPATH defined, the path to `tools.cc` need not be specified.

Here's the simplified file:

```
CXX       = g++
CPPFLAGS += -Iinclude/ -I../tools/
CXXFLAGS += -std=c++0x -Wall                (1)
VPATH     = ../tools                        (2)

binaries  = a b c

.PHONY : all                                (3)
all: $(binaries)

.PHONY : clean                              (3)
clean:
        rm -f $(binaries) *.o *~            (4)

b: b.c tools.o                              (5)
c: c.c tools.o                              (5)
```

Comment: The new thing I learned today is VPATH. I have used make a lot and its the first time I have heard this.

Comment: @LokiAstari I've learnt many things from your answers to the many C++ questions, so I am glad it is now not an entirely one-way street :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could use suffix rules (the .c.o part below) to tell make how to compile a c file. Then you can just tell the dependencies for each target.

```
CXX = g++
CXXFLAGS = -std=c++0x
INC = -Iinclude/ -I../tools/

binaries=01sum35\
     02evenfibs\
     03largestprimefactor\
     04largestpallyproduct\
     05smallestmultiple\
     06sumsquaredifference\
     07tenthousandfirstprime\
     08largestproductinseries\
     09specialpythagtriplet

all: $(binaries)

01sum35: 01sum35.cc

02evenfibs: 02evenfibs.cc

03largestprimefactor: 03largestprimefactor.cc 

04largestpallyproduct: 04largestpallyproduct.cc ../tools/tools.cc

05smallestmultiple: 05smallestmultiple.cc

06sumsquaredifference: 06sumsquaredifference.cc

07tenthousandfirstprime: 07tenthousandfirstprime.cc ../tools/tools.cc

08largestproductinseries: 08largestproductinseries.cc ../tools/tools.cc

09specialpythagtriplet: 09specialpythagtriplet.cc 

.cc.o:
    $(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) $< $(INC) -o $@

clean:
    rm -f $(binaries)
```